# How does the improve function interact with the names in this scope?

Tags: python

```py
def average(x, y):
    return (x + y) / 2

def improve(update, close, guess=1):
    while not close(guess):
        guess = update(guess)
    return guess

def approx_eq(x, y, tolerance=1e-3):
    return abs(x - y) < tolerance

def sqrt(a):
    def sqrt_update(x):
        return average(x, a/x)

    def sqrt_close(x):
        return approx_eq(x * x, a)

    return improve(sqrt_update, sqrt_close)

result = sqrt(256)
```

Hi, I am having a hard time understanding this Python code execution. I was taught that when a function is called, it will look for names following the LEGB rule (Local, Enclosing, Global, Built-in). When the `sqrt(256)` function is called, it returns `improve(sqrt_update,sqrt_close)`. Bear in mind that `sqrt_update(x)` and `sqrt_close(x)` are both functions defined in a totally different scope from where the improve function is defined.

So my question is, given that the improve function will look for names according to LEGB, how is it able to interact with `sqrt_update` and `sqrt_close`. I'm new to python, so would appreciate it an easy to understand response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the functions just like any other variable: You wouldn't worry about the following, would you:

```
def f(a):
  print(a)

x = "Hello World"
f(x)
```

You'd expect it to print "Hello World". Note how it was called `x` in the outer scope and `a` in the inner scope? That's just a different name for the same "thing" being passed around.

In Python you can do the same with functions, too. So when you pass `sqrt_update`, you pass an argument to the function. The function `improve`, however, calls this `update` and uses it as such.

Python keeps track of what objects are in use ("referenced") and keeps them around, even if you've left the function where they were created.

I hope this helped. Good luck on your ML journey!